# Parse iTunes Store feed with Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

Is there any Ruby code out there to help parse the iTunes Store feed?

There seems to be some PHP code:
[Parse iTunes RSS Atom feed with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965370/parse-itunes-rss-atom-feed-with-php)

but not Ruby. I've been Google'ing and SO'ing but haven't turned anything up so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this will help you. http://nokogiri.org/